# gitlab-ci build asp.net core docker

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am working on a gitlab CI/CD project to build an `asp.net core` application into a `docker`.
Currently I have 2 possible implementations in mind. The first one have the full logic in the `Dockerfile`, but I can't visualize the stages in Gitlab this way (build, test, publish). So I thought about moving the main logic to the `gitlab-ci.yml` file. But what bothers me now is that I have to manage the image `docker dotnet versions` on 2 places (sdk:3.1, aspnet:3.1.1-alpine3.10). Is it a good idea to deliver the version via `build-arg` or is there a more elegant solution?

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - docker

build:
  stage: build
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - cd src
    - dotnet restore --interactive
    - dotnet build --configuration Release
    - dotnet publish --configuration Release --output ../publish/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./publish/*.*
    expire_in: 1 week
  tags:
  - docker

test:
  stage: test
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - cd src
    - dotnet test --test-adapter-path:. --logger:"junit;LogFilePath=../../MyProject.xml"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./MyProject.xml
    reports:
      junit: ./MyProject.xml
  tags:
  - docker

docker:
  stage: docker
  image: docker:stable
  services:
    - docker:dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - docker login -u "gitlab-ci-token" -p "$CI_JOB_TOKEN" $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker build --tag "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA" --tag "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest" --build-arg EXECUTABLE=Test.WebApi.dll .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA"
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest"
  tags:
  - docker
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1.1-alpine3.10
ARG EXECUTABLE

WORKDIR /app
COPY /publish .

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS "http://*:5000"
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "Staging"
CMD ["dotnet", "$EXECUTABLE"]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is my solution, I have defined the variables above and replace them in the docker file with `sed`

My Solution have this two Projects

- Test.WebApi (WebApi Project)
- Test.WebApi.UnitTest (Unit Test Project)

@ThomasBrüggemann thanks for the Inspiration.

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
variables:
    PROJECT_NAME: "Test.WebApi"
    BUILD_IMAGE: "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1"
    RUNTIME_IMAGE: "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1.1-alpine3.10"

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - docker

build:
  stage: build
  image: $BUILD_IMAGE
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - cd src/$PROJECT_NAME
    - dotnet restore --interactive
    - dotnet build --configuration Release
    - dotnet publish --configuration Release --output ../../publish/
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./publish/*
    expire_in: 1 week
  tags:
  - docker
  
test:
  stage: test
  image: $BUILD_IMAGE
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - cd src/$PROJECT_NAME.UnitTest
    - dotnet test --test-adapter-path:. --logger:"junit;LogFilePath=../../UnitTestResult.xml"
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ./UnitTestResult.xml
    reports:
      junit: ./UnitTestResult.xml
  tags:
  - docker

docker:
  stage: docker
  image: docker:stable
  services:
    - docker:18.09.7-dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
  only:
    - master
  script:
    # Prepare Dockerfile
    - sed -i "s~\$DOCKERIMAGE~$RUNTIME_IMAGE~g" Dockerfile
    - sed -i 's/$ENVIRONMENT/Staging/g' Dockerfile
    - sed -i "s/\$ENTRYPOINT/$PROJECT_NAME.dll/g" Dockerfile

    # Process Dockerfile
    - docker login -u "gitlab-ci-token" -p "$CI_JOB_TOKEN" $CI_REGISTRY
    - docker build --tag "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA" --tag "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA"
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest"
  tags:
  - docker
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM $DOCKERIMAGE

WORKDIR /app
COPY /publish .

EXPOSE 5000/tcp

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS "http://*:5000"
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "$ENVIRONMENT"
CMD ["dotnet", "$ENTRYPOINT"]
```

Comment: did you got any problems with the Docker image in GitLab?

Comment: @NiAu What problems are they talking about?

Comment: that GitLab could not find the docker image of dotnet

Comment: It could be great if you can write an article for gitlab ci/cd pipeline with asp.net core 3.1/6.0. it will help starters

Answer (score 4):

Here some Version handling when tagging in GitLab-Pipeline:

```
script:
    - COMMIT_DATE=$(git log -1 --format=%cd --date=iso-strict | grep -o '\([0-9]*\)' | tr -d '\n')
    - VERSION_PREFIX=$CI_COMMIT_TAG
    - VERSION_SUFFIX="${COMMIT_DATE::-6}"
    - echo $VERSION_PREFIX-$VERSION_SUFFIX
    - sed -i "s:<VersionPrefix>.*</VersionPrefix>:<VersionPrefix>$VERSION_PREFIX</VersionPrefix>:g" [PROJECT].csproj
    - dotnet publish --version-suffix $VERSION_SUFFIX -c Release -o ./out
    - docker build --tag "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$VERSION_PREFIX"
only:
    - tags
```

In Project file must

```
<!-- Version is set by CI-Script do not modify manually -->
<VersionPrefix>0.0.0</VersionPrefix>
<Deterministic>False</Deterministic>
```

be set

Maybe this is helpful. 
Something similar can be done when build without tagging.